# How to add album art (picture/jpeg) to MP3s with ID3 Mass Tagger?

Tags: windows, mp3, id3

I need to mass-tag MP3 files, so, I found this tool from [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/10032/is-there-a-windows-command-line-tool-to-set-id3-tags-on-an-mp3-file): [ID3 mass tagger 0.78](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Tag-Editors/ID3-mass-tagger.shtml)

I couldn't find how to add images (album art/cover) thought that CLI (command line interface) tool.

How could I do that?

Comment: Please for more information check out below link:

http://superuser.com/questions/10032/is-there-a-windows-command-line-tool-to-set-id3-tags-on-an-mp3-file

and check out user "jeffm" answer.

hope that will help to understand more about what i asked for

Comment: so, no one knows anything about tagging mp3 files in CLI?